# Understanding the recent incident over Nupur Sharma statement from authentic & religious people in this group

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis, blasphemy

**Gist of the issue**: 
Regarding the nupur sharma incident, it is said she just mentioned what was in the Quran. So if that's the case then why there's so much backlash? What was wrong from her part?

**Long version:**
As-salamu alaykum, my brothers and sisters. I am not a muslim but would like to understand your religion better. I have recently came across a news which is doing the rounds & was wondering what's the exact cause of the event & what actually happened? And noboday was talking about the triggered event & all are reacting to reactions.

So I checked the video and its conversation. It was a regular news debate & the lady mentioned a sentence which is supposedly said to be written in Quran (I don't know authenticity of this matter). The statement was said in anger & in retaliation of the 1st person derogatory statement.

Now I could have quoted it & mentioned that source link but I avoided it just to avoid offending anyone. But at the same time I have seen many people have who doesn't have any idea on what's the actual issue & some haven't seen or heard the original source & the context in which it was given, but are reacting to the news / reports which includes UN representative spokesperson who himself told that he hasn't seen the main source but heard from sources but he condemn such actions and so do I.

Now my question to you all is that, is it true that her so called statements are written in Quran. I downloaded an english version of the Quran & tried to find it but couldn't find it in terms of exact statement or words. I maybe wrong but I need to talk & hear from the people that matters. So please give your inputs, so I can understand your religion better.

If anyone wants then I can provide source links. Sorry if my post offended anyone but my intent is to get to the bottom of this. Awaiting your response.

Comment: You should mention the gist of the issue as people are not going to go out of their way to find out what you are talking about. I have not heard what was said and have no intention of hearing it either. However from what I read in some news articles I think its about the marriage of Aisha, which is covered [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36485/).

Comment: Thanks for long article you provided. In short I can see it says, it was legitimate from islam point of view & it says she was in marriageable age. I will read it in detail as I get time but my question is if the person mentioned it as it is in quran then why there's so much backlash? The only bad thing i found is her anger, nothing else.

Comment: @UmH: but my question is if the person mentioned it as it is in Quran then why there's so much backlash?

Comment: @VarunKrish The intent of the person is to do character assassination. The attack on Ayesha’s age is nothing new. This idea dates back to the crusades. According to the academic Kecia Ali: "Accusations of lust and sensuality were a regular feature of medieval attacks on the prophet's character and, by extension, on the authenticity of Islam." Muslim hold all prophets in high regard. We have been ordered by Allah to add salutations when Prophets names are mentioned.

Comment: The backlash is because she said that to insult and denounce the Prophet. While the statement might be true, her intent of using it was to accuse the Prophet of debauchery, and she withheld the context that in ancient times people matured and married much earlier than today, and that such marriages were common for example even in [Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44019/). Muslims love the Prophet more than anyone else and are extremely sensitive about attacks on him. Also just for correction, the marriage of Aisha is from the Hadith and not the Quran.

Comment: Thanks @UmH. I got your point. It's almost like treating your parents & grandparents, you can't question or back answer them. You should give them their due respect. Am I right?

Comment: @UmH : BTW what is Hadith?